# array_push is not recognising my array

Tags: php, array-push

I have the following piece of PHP code which generates the following error:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /mnt/web109/e2/04/57677304/htdocs/wschaijk/projects/p5/advancedbuilder.php on line 393

```
if(isset($_POST['getAdvancedResults']))
        {
            $errorsarray = array();
            $continue = true;
            $controller = new ProductController();
            // Make a boolean that checks whether the query should be executed or not
            // If an error is found, this boolean becomes false and the query will not be run
            // Do check all field and add error message to an array using the array_push() function
            // After that, check using the boolean whether the query shall be run
            // Else: call print_form() and give it the array with error messages as argumen

            //cpu mobo compatbility check
            $CPU_comp = $controller -> get_single_entities(array("Id" => $_SESSION["advanced_builder"]["CPU"]))[0] -> get_compatibility();
            $MOBO_comp = $controller -> get_single_entities(array("Id" => $_SESSION["advanced_builder"]["Moederbord"]))[0] -> get_compatibility();
            //["LGA1151", "DDR4"] en ["LGA1151", "ATX", "DDR4"]
            $each_cpu_comp = explode(", ", $CPU_comp);
            $each_mobo_comp = explode(", ", $MOBO_comp);
            foreach ($each_cpu_comp as $comp)
            {
                foreach ($each_mobo_comp as $othercomp)
                {
                    //ram:
                    if ($comp != $othercomp && strpos($comp, "DDR") && strpos($othercomp, "DDR")) //DDR4 tegen DRR3 ->
                    {
                        $continue = false;
                        array_push($errorsarray, "RAM van CPU is niet compatible met RAM van het mnoederbord");
                    }
                    //socket
                    if ($comp != $othercomp && ((strpos($comp, "LGA") && strpos($othercomp, "LGA")) || (strpos($comp, "AM") && strpos($othercomp, "AM"))))
                    {
                        $continue = false;
                        array_push($errorsarray, "Socket van het moederbord en de cpu komen niet overeen");
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($continue)
            {
                    echo "<div class='row' style='text-align: center; margin-top: 5%;'>
                                  <div class='col-12'>
                                      <h3 style='color: green'>Systeem volledig compatibel! De correcte producten zijn aan uw winkelmand toegevoegd.</h3>
                                  </div>
                              </div>";
                    foreach ($_SESSION["advanced_builder"] as $product)
                    {
                        array_push($_SESSION["shoppingcart"], $product);
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                print_form($errorsarray);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print_form();

        }
```

when I try to run the code I get an error saying the array Im trying to insert the value into is null. What am I supposed to do to make the array_push work again?

Things I have tried:
- making the variable $errorsarray global
- creating the variable $errors array outside of the if(isset...

Comment: The error is clear... you try to push null array, define empty array before or dont push if null

Comment: It would be extreemly nice of you to identify for us mear mortals which of these few lines you showed us is **line 393** specially as I can see 3 places where you use `array_push()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly all the array_push functions generate this error

Comment: @InovandenBerg Do you always push into the same array though? The error says, that that array is not initialized.

Comment: You can use `$errorsarray[] = "RAM ...";` instead of array push. try it and tell us.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing line 393 (which the error states) is the following:

```
array_push($_SESSION["shoppingcart"], $product);
```

So you have to make sure that `$_SESSION["shoppingcart"]` is an array.

#### A possible solution

Beneath `$errorsarray = array();` you could write the following:

```
$_SESSION["shoppingcart"] = array();
```

Comment: This was part of the solution, the $_SESSION["shoppingcart"] was protected from partial editing (according to my groupmate) so I had to assign the session array to a temporary array, and then overwrite the array in the session, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your code, before the `foreach` statements, you have to define the `errorsarray`.

If you take a look at the php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) you can see that you need to define the empty array in this simple way:

```
$errorsarray = array();
```

If the error refers to the arra_push on the `$_SESSION` variable, you have to check if you have the `session_start();` line before this code.

I think also that you have to define before the `foreach` statements, the `$_SESSION["shoppingcart"]` as an empty array too:

```
$_SESSION["shoppingcart"] = array();
```

Comment: Keep trying, still not valid PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly I made a mistake, now it should be fine

Comment: Yup, and if you look at line 3 of the OP's code you will see they already did this

Comment: are you getting the error on the array_push($_SESSION["shoppingcart"] ...line?